# Covering number bound for the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(E)$, with $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, packing-and-covering

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ have finite diameter $D(E)= \sup_{x,x' \in E}\Vert x-x' \Vert_n$. Let $W^{1,1}(E)$ denote the class of functions $f$ on $E$ admitting integrable first order weak derivative $f_j$ with respect to the $j$-th argument, for $j=1, \ldots,n$. Then the Sobolev norm of $f$ can be defined as
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{W^{1,1}(E)}=\Vert f \Vert_{L^1(E)}+\sum_{j=1}^n \Vert f_j \Vert_{L^1(E)},
$$
where $\Vert h \Vert_{L^1(E)}\int_E |h(x)| \text{Leb}(dx)$ and $\text{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure. The induced distance is thus
$$
d_{W^{1,1}}(h,f)=\Vert h-f \Vert_{W^{1,1}(E)}.
$$
The covering number
$$
N_{M}:=N(\epsilon,\{f \in W^{1,1}(E): \Vert f \Vert_{W^{1,1}(E)}<M\},d_{W^{1,1}})
$$
is the minimum number of $d_{W^{1,1}}$-balls of radius $\epsilon$ needed to cover
$$
\{f \in W^{1,1}(E): \Vert f \Vert_{W^{1,1}(E)}<M\},
$$
where $M>0$.

**Question:** do you know any reference providing an upper-bound for $N_M$ which explicitly depends on $D(E)$ and $M$?